# Appending a single character to a dynamic character array in C

Tags: c, character, concatenation

How do I append a character to a `char*`?
So...

```
char* thingy = "test";
char* another = "hello world";

thingy += another[6];

printf("%s\n", thingy);
```

I wan't the output to be:

> testw

However, I get this output

> at address %p

edit:

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no string arithmetic in C, so you can't do it that way.

However, there's `strcat()`, which you can use (as long as there's room for those characters):

```
char thingy[256] = "Hello World";

strcat(thingy, "!");

// thingy is now "Hello World!"
```

Although it's important to note that you should always check string lengths and be careful when doing such things.

If you'd like to add a single character rather than a string, you can either copy that character to a string:

```
char thingy[256] = "Hello World";

char dummy[] = "#";

dummy[0] = '!';
strcat(thingy, dummy);

// thingy is now "Hello World!"
```

Or do it the manual way:

```
char thingy[256] = "Hello World";

unsigned int len = strlen(thingy);

thingy[len] = '!';      // Append character
thingy[len + 1] = '\0'; // Readd termination

// thingy is now "Hello World!"
```

Comment: Isn't modifying string literals undefined?

Comment: doesn't the first method using strcat take const char * as the second argument? So I can't do that if I'm using line[6]?

Comment: @Ben By using `char[]` rather than `char*` you're creating a copy.

Comment: I'm referring to `char *dummy = "#"; dummy[0] = '!'`

Comment: @freefouran Correct, see the other two snippets for appending a single character (the first one is probably sub-optimal to do).

Comment: @Ben Oops! Correct :)

Comment: I did it a little bit differently

Answer (score 1):

Your only option in this case is to reallocate the char*'s memory so that you can get a larger string.

First, you will need the length of the original string, then you must add 1 to it as the strlen function does not include the null terminator:

```
char* thingy = "test";
char* another = "hello world";

int len = strlen(thingy);
char* thingy = realloc(thingy, (len + 2) * sizeof(char));
thingy[len] = another[6];
thingy[len +1] = '\0';

printf("%s\n", thingy);
```

If you have access to C++, however, a better approach is to use the std::string object:

```
std::string thingy = "test";
std::string another = "hello world";

thingy += another[6];
printf("%s\n", thingy.c_str());
```

Since strings are containers, there are myriad ways to approach the problem:

```
thingy.push_back(another[6]);

thingy.append(another, 6, 1);

thingy.insert(thingy.end(), another[6]);
```

Another benefit of std strings is that they handle the null terminator for you, so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: You don't have to add 2 characters when reallocating; one should be enough (since the appended char will take the previous terminator's spot, so you'll just need one more byte for the new terminator).

Comment: strlen does not include the length of the null terminator, so if you call realloc(..., len + 1), you'll realloc the same size array.

Comment: You cannot realloc(thingie) here.  The effect of the initialiser is to create thingie with type pointer to char pointing at an anonymous object of type array of char.  Further, the effect of attempting to modify the contents of the array are undefined.  This leaves it open to the compiler to set a pointer to a collection of constant strings.  There is no suggestion that the array of char is to be malloc'ed.

Answer (score 0):

`thingy` is a pointer (`*`) to `char`, i.e., the address of the first character of the string `"test"`. Arithmetic on `thingy` changes the address to which it points:

```
thingy += another[6];
```

This adds the integer value of the `char` at the address `another + 6` to the address pointed to by `thingy`. This is beyond the end of the string `"test"` and thus undefined behaviour - it just happens that your program has the string `"at address %p"`.

Also, the string pointed to by `thingy` is a constant so you cannot append to it. You could make it an array, e.g., `char thingy[MAX_LENGTH_OF_THINGY] = "test";` instead, and then do something like `thingy[4] = another[6]; thingy[5] = '\0';` (note the need to NUL-terminate C-strings). Or you can create a new string altogether, e.g., by `malloc`ing enough memory and copying the original + the additional character to it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes more sense to me now :)

Answer (score -1):

The string you append onto should not be a literal. If you had:

```
char thingy[10] = "test";
```

You can:

```
int len = strlen(thingy);
thingy[len] = another[6];
thingy[len+1] = '\0';
```

Comment: And what if he wants a longer string than 10 chars?

Comment: it's just an example. Replace 10 with a sufficiently large buffer size.